# Find the area bounded by given equation

Tags: geometry

> Find the area bounded by the graph of $|x|+|y|=\frac{1}{4}|x+15|$

I am having difficulty finding what figure the equation forms. I do not know how to deal with the multiple absolute values.

Can someone show me what are the variations of the equation since it has these multiple terms with absolute value?

Comment: It looks like a [kite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kite_(geometry)); consider the four quadrants

Comment: It is hard to understand what is meant by "bounded" as there is no bound for $x\to \pm\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

For $x \ge 0, y \ge 0$, $x+y = \frac{1}{4}(x+15)$
or, $3x+4y-15 = 0$. (Not possible for $x \gt 5$ as you get $y \lt 0$)

For $x \ge 0, y \le 0$, $x-y = \frac{1}{4}(x+15)$
or, $3x-4y-15 = 0$. (Not possible for $x \gt 5$ as you get $y \gt 0$)

For, $-15 \le x \le 0, y \ge 0$, $-x+y = \frac{1}{4}(x+15)$
or, $5x-4y+15 = 0$. (Not possible for $x \lt -3$ as you get $y \lt 0$)

For, $-15 \le x \le 0, y \le 0$, $-x-y = \frac{1}{4}(x+15)$
or, $5x+4y+15 = 0$. (Not possible for $x \lt -3$ as you get $y \gt 0$)

For, $x \le -15, y \ge 0$, $-x+y = \frac{1}{4}(-x-15)$
or, $3x-4y-15 = 0$. (Not possible as you get $y \lt 0$)

For, $x \le -15, y \le 0$, $-x-y = \frac{1}{4}(-x-15)$
or, $3x+4y-15 = 0$. (Not possible as you get $y \gt 0$)

Comment: You get a quadrilateral. $x \lt -3$ does not give anything meaningful and have to be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$f(x,y) = |x| + |y| - \tfrac{1}{4}|x + 15|.$$  Then if $x > 0$ and $y > 0$, we have $$f(x,y) = x + y - \tfrac{1}{4}(x+15) = \tfrac{3}{4}x + y - \tfrac{15}{4}.$$  Setting this to $0$ gives us a line in the first quadrant.  Similarly, if $x > 0$ and $y < 0$, we have $$f(x,y) = x - y - \tfrac{1}{4}(x+15) = \tfrac{3}{4}x - y - \tfrac{15}{4},$$ which is another line, this time in the fourth quadrant.

In the second and third quadrants, we also need to consider the cases where $x < -15$ versus $-15 < x < 0$: in the latter, we have $$f(x,y) = -x + y -\tfrac{1}{4}(x+15)$$ but in the former, we have $$f(x,y) = -x - y + \tfrac{1}{4}(x+15).$$  But it turns out that the former case results in a line that does not pass through the second quadrant--it is the same line as in the fourth quadrant; therefore, we ignore it.  The two sub-cases in the third quadrant are handled similarly.

The result of these cases is that they describe four lines that bound a convex quadrilateral with vertices $$\{(5,0), (0, \tfrac{15}{4}), (-3,0), (0, -\tfrac{15}{4})\}.$$  The area of this region is easily computed from these vertices.

Answer (score 0):

If you reorder the terms first,
$$\lvert y \rvert = \frac{1}{4}\lvert x + 15 \rvert - \lvert x \rvert$$
you should realize you only need to consider
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{4}\lvert x + 15 \rvert - \lvert x \rvert$$
where $f(x) \ge 0$, because the figure is symmetric vertically, around the $x$ axis; bounded above by $y = f(x)$ and below by $y = -f(x)$.

To determine the ranges, you need to first find where each absolute value expression ($\lvert \cdot \rvert$) is zero.

Here, they are $x = -15$ and $x = 0$.

This means we have three ranges: $x \le -15$, $-15 \le x \le 0$, and $0 \le x$.

In the first range, $x \le -15$, we have $x + 15 \le 0$ and $x \le 0$, so we have
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{4}\bigr(-(x + 15)\bigr) - \bigr(-x\bigr) = \frac{3}{4} x - \frac{15}{4}$$

In the second range, $-15 \le x \le 0$, we have $x + 15 \ge 0$ but $x \le 0$, so we have
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{4}\bigr(x + 15\bigr) - \bigr(-x\bigr) = \frac{5}{4} x + \frac{15}{4}$$

In the third range, $x \ge 0$, we have $x + 15 \ge 0$ and $x \ge 0$, so we have
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{4}\bigr(x + 15\bigr) - \bigr(x\bigr) = \frac{15}{4} - \frac{3}{4} x$$

The next step is to find the points where $f(x)$ is zero, because those are the leftmost and rightmost points of the figure.  It is important to remember that when we inspect $f(x)$ within a range, and find $f(x) = 0$, we have found $f(x) = 0$ only if $x$ is within that range also. (Otherwise we just found where the line *would* intersect the $x$ axis, if we were to extend it.)

In this case, in the first range $x \le -15$, for $f(x) = 0$:
$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{3}{4} x - \frac{15}{4} & = 0 \\
3 x &= 15 \\
x &= 5 \\
\end{aligned}$$
However, because this is not within the range $x \le -15$, this is not a point we need to consider at all.  (Effectively, it is just the point where the lines in this range would intersect, but because that point is outside this range, it has no use for us.)

In the second range, $-15 \le x \le 0$, $f(x) = 0$ is
$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{5}{4} x + \frac{15}{4} & = 0 \\
5 x & = - 15 \\
x & = - 3 \\
\end{aligned}$$
So, the figure is bounded at $x = -3$ on the left side.

In the third range, $x \ge 0$, $f(x) = 0$ is
$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{15}{4} - \frac{3}{4} x & = 0 \\
3 x & = 15 \\
x & = 5 \\
\end{aligned}$$
and therefore the figure is bounded at $x = 5$ on the right side.

Because we know the figure is within range $-3 \le x \le 5$, we only need to consider the two ranges:
$$\lvert y \rvert = f(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{5}{4} x + \frac{15}{4}, & x \le 0 \\
\frac{15}{4} - \frac{3}{4} x, & x \ge 0 \\
\end{cases}$$

This also means that our figure is formed by four (axis-aligned) right triangles, one in each quadrant.  We already know their bases ($3$ and $5$); their heights are all $f(0)$:
$$f(0) = \frac{5}{4} \cdot 0 + \frac{15}{4} = \frac{15}{4} - \frac{3}{4} \cdot 0 = \frac{15}{4}$$

Since the area of an (axis-aligned) right triangle is $b \cdot w / 2$, where $b$ is the base and $w$ is the width, and each pair of triangles (vertically, across the $x$ axis) are the same, the total area is
$$A = 2\left(\frac{3 \cdot 15}{2 \cdot 4}\right) + 2\left(\frac{5 \cdot 15}{2 \cdot 4}\right) = \frac{45}{4} + \frac{75}{4} = 30$$